# TYPO3 EXT:webkitpdf does not render PDF file

Tags: typo3, wkhtmltopdf

Using EXT:webkitpdf with TYPO3 7.6 worked very well. But "suddenly" the PDFs were corrupted or no PDF file was written (just empty temp-files). There is also no entry in the EXT:webkitpdf-Log.

Answer (score 0):

After some investitgation I found this in my TYPO3-error-Log:

10-02-17 12:49 - core: Core: Error handler (FE): PHP Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent in /is/htdocs/wpXXXXXXXXX/www/typo3_sources/typo3_src-7.6.13/typo3/sysext/frontend/Classes/Utility/CompressionUtility.php line 54

Okay, it's the FE:compression!

After turning off [FE][compressionLevel]=0 in InstallTool, all works fine again!